# Marie Curie fellowship - is it possible to defer the start?

Tags: marie-curie, deferral

I haven't won any MSCA fellowship yet, but in case I were to win at the next round, would it be possible to defer the beginning of the fellowship? (I have an assistant professorship and am involved in a project as PI, it would be better to wait for the end of the probation period for me and for the end of the project, so a deferral of 6-8 months)
Thanks a lot

Comment: Why don't you ask the program manager?

Comment: Why do you want to apply for a MSC as an assistant professor?

Answer (score 0):

There's not a clear answer from the European Commission, but [this guide](https://marie-sklodowska-curie-actions.ec.europa.eu/sites/default/files/2021-05/implementation_guide_for_msca_if_fellows_v1.pdf) is a good place to start. I'd suggest following the section called "In case of problems."

Generally, academic fellowship programs let you postpone (or probably more accurately, "revise your start state") for a number of reasons. I'd recommend, when you ask for a revised start date, to cite that you want to ensure the integrity of your current project and would benefit from additional time. Best of luck!